Is the "set" of all well-founded sets not well-founded? Question about Mirimanoff paradox.
First, let me state the definition of well-founded set that I work with: a set $X$ is well-founded if there is no infinite sequence $\langle x_0, x_1, x_2,\dots\rangle$ of members of $X$ s.t. $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\dots$
Now to the question: there is a less known paradox of naive set theory which concerns the concept of well-founded sets -- I know it under the name Mirimanoff paradox -- it is discussed e.g. here and should go something like this:

Consider the set $W$ of all well-founded sets
If $W$ is well-founded, then $W\in W$. But then there would be an infinite sequence $W\ni W\ni W\dots$. So $W$ would not be well-founded, so $W\notin W$
If $W\notin W$, then we should be somehow able to reason that $W$ is actually well-founded, thus $W\in W$.
So $W\in W \leftrightarrow W\notin W$

My question concerns point 3 -- I don't know how such reasoning could be done. Consider the following sequence of naive (not ZFC sets) sets (natural numbers represent von Neumann ordinals):

$A_0=\{1,A_1\}$
$A_1=\{2,A_2\}$
$A_2=\{3,A_3\}$
$\dots$

Thus, if $x\neq y$, then $A_x \neq A_y$. Thus, each $A_x$ is well-founded, so it should belong to $W$. But then there is an infinite sequence $A_0\ni A_1\ni A_2\ni\dots$ of members of $W$, thus $W$ is not well-founded. My point here is that we can reason that $W$ is not well-founded even if we do not assume that $W\in W$, so why can't we just proclaim that $W\notin W$ and be fine? What is the reasoning of point 3? Am I using a different definition of well-founded set than the definition used in Mirimanoff paradox?

Your definition of well-founded is usually only used for transitive sets.

But I don't see how you can define $A_0$. It involves infinitely many operations, and you don't seem to have justified that. For example you seem to claim that ${{{...}}}$ is always a set, but this is false in ZFC.

@Trebor I sure don't want to claim anything about ZFC, only about naive set theory. It may very well be that I am using too restricted definition of well-foundedness, I'll look into it again, thanks.

You can't construct that set in naive set theory either. (Of course you can cheat by first proving Russel's paradox, and then use that to prove everything, but I don't see any other way you can construct your $A_0$.)

@Trebor I did not think about that at all, I'll check that asap, thanks.

As was pointed out in the comments, I was indeed using too restrictive definition of well-founded sets.
Usual definition of well-founded set is the following: a set $X$ is well-founded if there is no infinite sequence $\langle x_0, x_1, x_2\dots\rangle$ of members of transitive closure of $X$ s.t. $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\dots$.
With such a definition, Mirimanoff paradox is easily obtainable.
With my restricted definition, the paradox may not obtain, although my reasoning about the set $A_0$ is questionable, since it may very well be that $A_0$ is not constructible even in the naive set theory.
